# SSAS - setting a slice

Tags: ssas, bids

I've partitioned my cube to improve processing time. But I doubt it improved my query times. I read that I have to set the slice property.
So my partition query cuts it by

```
year 2012 and older (ie < year 2013)
the year 2013
and year 2014 and onwards
```

I'm wondering how i set my slice? this don't seem to work and I get an error.

```
[dim_report_year] < 2013
[dim_report_year] = 2013
[dim_report_year] > 2013
```

the restrictions imposed on partition slice where violated

Thanks.

Comment: I've never used the slice property myself, but it seems unlikely you would use the entire dimension to set it.  I would think you would have to use a specific attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the slice definition you can use tuples only. You cannot use sets or conditions. Therefore you can create a new attribute with 3 values(x<2013, x=2013, x>2013) in time dimension, then you can use this new attribute in the slice definition.